# Which font filetype is best used in iOS Applications?

Tags: objective-c, fonts, file-type, uifont

A client has just bought a licensing bundle for a custom font of which he would like to use in our application, containing eot, svg, ttf, woff filetypes.

Which filetype would be best to be used in iOS Applications? I'd image SVG is for the reason of it being lightweight and scalable, but TTF tends to be the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TTF. Custom TTF font support has has been included in iOS since 3.2. It is as scalable as SVG, but has much better internal text layout metric support (as it is an actual font format).